# Write a program to output all palindromic times displayed by a 24 hour digital clock (e.g. 13:31)

Tags: c, palindrome

I am attempting to write a program that will output all palindromic times show below using C-Programming:

```
00:00
01:10
02:20
03:30
04:40
05:50
10:01
11:11
12:21
13:31
14:41
15:51
20:02
21:12
22:22
23:32
```

I know to treat the hours and the minutes as two separate variables rather than as an actual time. Also there will be a few counters to increment the hours and minutes but not sure exactly where to head any ideas is much appreciated?

Comment: You don't need 2 variables: one string is the reverse of another!

Comment: Good luck, please return to SO when you have some code to show and we gladly help you if you get stuck at something. Two for-loops, one for hours and one for minutes; at each iteration check if hours == minutes (using strings, with one of them reversed)

Comment: One for-loop that counts from 0 to 23, skipping numbers where the second digit is 6 thru 9. Then print the number forwards for hours and backwards for minutes.

Comment: {h | 0..23},  {m |  h / 10 + (h % 10) * 10} {if m < 60, printf("%d:%d\n", h, m)}

Comment: You can generate all possible hours, and for each hour, generate the minute string as reverse of the hour string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the perfect answer you want

```
    #include <stdio.h>

int pallindrome(int loop)
{
    if (loop >= 10)
    {
        int temp, temp1 = 0, sum = 0;
        for(temp = 0; temp < 2;temp++)
        {
            temp1 = loop % 10;
            loop = loop / 10;
            sum = sum * 10 + temp1;
        }
        return(sum);
    }
    else
    {
        return(loop * 10);
    }
}
int main(void) {
    // your code goes here
    int a=0;
    int loop=0;
    for (loop=0; loop<=59; loop++)
    {
        a = pallindrome(loop);
        if (a < 60)
        printf("%.2d:%.2d\n", loop,a);  
    }
    return 0;
}
```

See the output here: http://ideone.com/54ouHv

Comment: the posted answer has a path through the  pallindrome function that does not contain a `return value` statement .  (the compiler raises a warnings message.  Tto correct, make the outer control a if/else rather than two successive `if` statements

Comment: @user3629249 thank you for the advice. I will surely correct it.

Comment: @user3629249 I hope now it is won't give a warning message.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int i;
  char h[3] = {'0', '0', 0};

  for(i = 0 ; i < 24 ; i++)
  {
    if((i % 10) < 6)
    {
      snprintf(h, 3, "%02d", i);
      printf("%s:%c%c\n", h, h[1], h[0]);
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

The output of this code: http://ideone.com/N0L4ft

Answer (score 1):

- May be this is what you want,

  ```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <time.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <string.h>
  int main()
  {
    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm * timeinfo;

    time ( &rawtime );
    timeinfo = localtime ( &rawtime );
    printf ( "Current local time and date: %s\n", asctime (timeinfo) );
    char hour[20], mints[20], rec[10];
    snprintf(hour, sizeof(hour), "%d", timeinfo->tm_hour);
    snprintf(mints, sizeof(mints), "%d", timeinfo->tm_min);

    int length = strlen(hour);
    int j = 0;
    for(int i = length; i > 0; i--)
    {
           rec[j++] = hour[i - 1];
    }
    rec[j] = '\0';

    if(strcmp(rec, mints) == 0)
        printf ( "%d %d", timeinfo->tm_hour, timeinfo->tm_min );
    return 0;
  }
  ```

Comment: This is not giving any output as desired. Check your output here: http://ideone.com/0pv863